# Excel Workbook with VBA macro taking a long time to open

Tags: excel, vba

I have written a macro to automate my daily task of filtering a value and then copy in a different sheet. My Macro is done but when I try to open the excel file it takes longer time to open.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    Dim autofiltrng As Range
    Dim total_data As Range
    Dim specific_column As Range

    With Application
        .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .DisplayStatusBar = False
        .EnableEvents = False
    End With

    On Error Resume Next

    Sheets("MasterRolePLMap").ShowAllData

    On Error GoTo 0
    'Filter the data as per CompetencyView

    Sheets("MasterRolePLMap").Range("A1").AutoFilter field:=1, Criteria1:=Sheets("CompetencyView").Range("C5").Value

    With Sheets("MasterRolePLMap").AutoFilter.Range
        On Error Resume Next

        'Focus only on visible cells

        Set autofiltrng = .Offset(1, 0).Resize(.Rows.Count - 1, 1).Resize(.Rows.Count - 1, 1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
        On Error GoTo 0
    End With

    If autofiltrng Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "No Data to Copy"

    Else
        Sheets("MasterRolePLMap").Activate

        Sheets("MasterRolePLMap").Range("D:D").Select
        Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Select
        Selection.Copy
        Sheets("CompetencyView").Activate
        Sheets("CompetencyView").Cells(14, 2).Select
        Sheets("CompetencyView").Paste

        Sheets("MasterRolePLMap").Activate

        Sheets("MasterRolePLMap").Range("F:F").Select
        Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Select
        Selection.Copy
        Sheets("CompetencyView").Activate
        Sheets("CompetencyView").Cells(14, 3).Select
        Sheets("CompetencyView").Paste

        Sheets("MasterRolePLMap").Activate

        Sheets("MasterRolePLMap").Range("E:E").Select
        Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Select
        Selection.Copy
        Sheets("CompetencyView").Activate
        Sheets("CompetencyView").Cells(14, 4).Select
        Sheets("CompetencyView").Paste

        Sheets("MasterRolePLMap").Activate

        Sheets("MasterRolePLMap").Range("G:G").Select
        Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Select
        Selection.Copy
        Sheets("CompetencyView").Activate
        Sheets("CompetencyView").Cells(14, 5).Select
        Sheets("CompetencyView").Paste

        Sheets("MasterRolePLMap").Activate

        Sheets("MasterRolePLMap").Range("C:C").Select
        Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Select
        Selection.Copy
        Sheets("CompetencyView").Activate
        Sheets("CompetencyView").Cells(14, 6).Select
        Sheets("CompetencyView").Paste
    End If

    Sheets("CompetencyView").Activate
    Set total_data = Sheets("CompetencyView").Range("B15:F1048576")
    Set specific_column = Sheets("CompetencyView").Range("E15:E1048576")
    total_data.Sort key1:=specific_column, order1:=xlAscending

    If IsEmpty(Range("B15").Value) = True Then
        With Range(Range("B14"), Range("B14").End(xlToRight)).Borders
            .LineStyle = xlcontinous
            .Weight = xlThin
        End With
    Else
        With Range(Range("B14"), Range("B14").End(xlToRight).End(xlDown)).Borders
            .LineStyle = xlcontinous
            .Weight = xlThin
        End With
    End If

    With Application
        .Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic

        .ScreenUpdating = True
        .DisplayStatusBar = True
        .EnableEvents = True
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: how long would you classify as a "long time"? Also, take a look at this question regrading [How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba) because using `activate` and `select` can slow your macros

Comment: If this is the only code, then it should have no effect on how long it takes to open, unless the loading triggers this routine somehow... and you didnt include anything that would indicate that.

Comment: Few things I would note:

1) are there any sheets with too many rows? Sometimes users can accidentally add too many rows to a sheet and then all rows will load on open. Check each tab, and if your right hand side bar is too small for the amount of data, then you might have a sheet with too many rows. I recommend copying and pasting the data to a new sheet, deleting the old sheet, and renaming the new one.

2) save as a .xlsb which can often times reduce the overall file size. xlsb files are still macro enabled sheets.

Let me know if either of these solutions solve your issue. Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

```
Set total_data = Sheets("CompetencyView").Range("B15:F1048576")
Set specific_column = Sheets("CompetencyView").Range("E15:E1048576")
```

I think these lines might be the issue. I think it is what is generating too many rows. Try specifying the range:

```
i = Sheets("CompetencyView").Cells(rows.count,6).End(xlUp).row
Set total_data = Sheets("CompetencyView").Range(Cells(15,2),Cells(i,6))
i = Sheets("CompetencyView").Cells(rows.count,5).End(xlUp).row
Set specific_column = Sheets("CompetencyView").Range(Cells(15,5),Cells(i,5))
```

Let me know if that helped.

Comment: that helps !! Thank You